# Unable to install Snipping Tool on Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-store-app, microsoft-store, snipping-tool

A while ago, I had problems with Windows 11 Snip & Sketch / Snipping Tool. I could start a screenshot with WIN + SHIFT + S, but the notification to then edit and annotate the screenshot would not show up. I tried the usual fixes of repairing and resetting the application, but this did not resolve the issue.

I next tried to uninstall and reinstall the application. I believe I uninstalled it via the Microsoft Store, though, it was a while ago. However, I have been unable to reinstall Snipping Tool for some time. The error I get in the Windows Store is [Something unexpected happened. Reporting this problem will help us understand it better. You can wait a bit and try again or restart your device. That may help. Code: 0x80073D05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVHz7.png).

I have tried deleting the Snip&Sketch entries in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository and C:\Program Files\WindowsApps. I have also tried to remove the entry in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Extensions\ContractId\windows.appExecutionAlias\PackageId.

I know this is only the snipping tool, but it's quite useful for my work.

I found found the following information:

Event Viewer: System Logs

```
Installation Started: Windows has started installing the following update: 9MZ95KL8MR0L-Microsoft.ScreenSketch
Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80073D05: 9MZ95KL8MR0L-Microsoft.ScreenSketch.
```

Event Viewer: Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Restricted

```
Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppxBundleManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80073CF6. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
```

Event Viewer: Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational

```
Started deployment Stage operation on a package with main parameter 3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d and Options RequiredContentGroupOnly and StageAdditionalRelatedSetUpdateRequiredPackages. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\a6d32898-a2a5-4b0e-beef-d5d670f1d8a5_S-1-5-18_1.rslc for Stage Operation on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Deployment Stage operation on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe has been de-queued and is running for user SID S-1-5-18.

Bundle Uri x-windowsupdate://790CB0E2-A319-43BD-9391-F89D47D9209B/DE4F0463-7DB2-48EE-959C-70E02541F4E6/3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d contains packages: "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_x64.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_ARM64.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_arm64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-el.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-el_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-nl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-nl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-am.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-am_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sq.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sq_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-mk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-mk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-zh-hant.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hant_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sv.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sv_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-cs.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-cs_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-kn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-kn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ta.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ta_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ro.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ro_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-it.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-it_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-et.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-et_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-th.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-th_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-vi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-vi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-tr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-tr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-pt.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-pt_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-he.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-he_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-gl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-gl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-pl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-pl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ar.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ar_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-km.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-km_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-de.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-de_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-es.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-es_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-nb.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-nb_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ja.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ja_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hu.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hu_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-da.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-da_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ko.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ko_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-zh-hans.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lt.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lt_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sr-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sr-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-az-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-az-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fil-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fil-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ms.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ms_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-eu.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-eu_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-af.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-af_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-uk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-uk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lo.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lo_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ru.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ru_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ml.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ml_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lv.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lv_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-150.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-150_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-100.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-bg.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-bg_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-is.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-is_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ca.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ca_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-uz-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-uz-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-id.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-id_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-te.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-te_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-125.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-125_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fa.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fa_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-kk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-kk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-400.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-400_8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Successfully added the following uri(s) to be processed:  x-windowsupdate://790CB0E2-A319-43BD-9391-F89D47D9209B/DE4F0463-7DB2-48EE-959C-70E02541F4E6/3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d x-windowsupdate://790CB0E2-A319-43BD-9391-F89D47D9209B/DE4F0463-7DB2-48EE-959C-70E02541F4E6/3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d\SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_x64.msix x-windowsupdate://790CB0E2-A319-43BD-9391-F89D47D9209B/DE4F0463-7DB2-48EE-959C-70E02541F4E6/3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d\SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-100.msix.

Starting validation and setting the Trust Label on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with flags 0x9.

Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe has Trust Label already. Flags: 0x9

Finished validation and setting the Trust Label on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with flags 0x9.

Starting validation and setting the Trust Label on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe with flags 0x9.

Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe has Trust Label already. Flags: 0x9

Finished validation and setting the Trust Label on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe with flags 0x9.

Deployment Stage operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d)  finished successfully.

Deployment Stage operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (3051d4732547e861c2ea74c80f14da26dba6666d)  finished successfully.

Moving package folder \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2302.4.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe to \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2302.4.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe7bea325e-401e-4c97-9a8c-7f59bd8467c3. Result: 0x80070002.

Moving package folder \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2302.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe to \\?\C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Deleted\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2302.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe52514e24-612b-48af-a64a-94c7fc657305. Result: 0x80070002.

Started deployment StageUserData operation on a package with main parameter Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe and Options 0 and 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\a6d32898-a2a5-4b0e-beef-d5d670f1d8a5_S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004_2.rslc for StageUserData Operation on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Deployment StageUserData operation on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe has been de-queued and is running for user SID S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004.

Successfully added the following uri(s) to be processed:  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml.

Deployment StageUserData operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppxManifest.xml)  finished successfully.

Started deployment RegisterByPackageFamilyName operation on a package with main parameter Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe and Options RegisterHighestVersion,FailIfNeedsRemediation and SkipDeploymentOperationRpcCallerIsAdminCheck. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\a6d32898-a2a5-4b0e-beef-d5d670f1d8a5_S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004_3.rslc for Register Operation on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Deployment Register operation on package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe has been de-queued and is running for user SID S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004.

The file system entries for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe could not be cleaned up after reboot. The package is removed from the purge list.

Bundle Uri C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml contains packages: "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_x64.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_ARM64.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_arm64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-el.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-el_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-nl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-nl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-am.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-am_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sq.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sq_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-mk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-mk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-zh-hant.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hant_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sv.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sv_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-cs.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-cs_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-kn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-kn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ta.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ta_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ro.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ro_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-it.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-it_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-et.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-et_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-th.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-th_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-vi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-vi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-tr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-tr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-pt.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-pt_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-he.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-he_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-gl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-gl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-pl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-pl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ar.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ar_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-km.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-km_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-de.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-de_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-es.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-es_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-nb.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-nb_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ja.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ja_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hu.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hu_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-da.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-da_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ko.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ko_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-zh-hans.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-zh-hans_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lt.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lt_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sr-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sr-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-az-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-az-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fil-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fil-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ms.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ms_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-eu.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-eu_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-af.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-af_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-uk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-uk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-hi.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-hi_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lo.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lo_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ru.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ru_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-sl.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-sl_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ml.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ml_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-lv.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-lv_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-150.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-150_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-100.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-bg.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-bg_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-is.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-is_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-ca.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-ca_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fr.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fr_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-uz-latn.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-uz-latn_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-id.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-id_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-te.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-te_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-125.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-125_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-fa.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-fa_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_language-kk.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.language-kk_8wekyb3d8bbwe "SnippingToolApp_11.2303.17.0_scale-400.msix": Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-400_8wekyb3d8bbwe.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.26706.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30035.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.29016.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.29231.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

Package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop_14.0.30035.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe does not satisfy a dependency for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Reason: The package's version is lower than the required MinVersion.

User S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1001 had outdated package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2302.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe, which will be updated to Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. User was online: false.

Finished resolving action lists. DeploymentRequest action lists: addPackageList: Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_neutral_split.scale-100_8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe destagePackageList: Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2302.4.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2302.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.

About to service package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting the package state to disabled returned with 0x0.

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\resources.49e9aad9.pri : Created shared merged PRI file

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004-MergedResources-0.pri : Linked user-specific merged PRI file

Error while deleting the existing application data. Error Code: 0x80070005.

An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

error 0x80073D05: While processing the request, the system failed to register the windows.stateExtension extension due to the following error: An error occurred while deleting the package's previously existing application data.

error 0x80073D05: Cannot register the request because the following error was encountered during the registration of the windows.stateExtension extension: An error occurred while deleting the package's previously existing application data.

An internal error occurred with error 0x800703FA. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

error 0x800703FA: While reverting the request, the system failed to de-register the windows.stateExtension extension due to the following error: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\resources.49e9aad9.pri : Shared merged file still in use

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004-MergedResources-0.pri : Deleted

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\S-1-5-21-3044634543-187124829-2306481523-1004-MergedResources-*.pri : No user-specific merged files found

Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\resources.49e9aad9.pri : Deleted

error 0x80073CF6: Cannot register the Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe package due to the following error: Package could not be registered.

The last successful state reached was SingletonRegisterAdd. Failure occurred before reaching the next state RegistrationChanged. hr: 0x80073CF6

error 0x8007139F: While removing the request, the system failed to de-register the windows.MRT extension due to the following error: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

Finished servicing package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2303.17.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. Setting the package state to enabled returned with 0x0.

Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (AppxBundleManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80073CF6. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

AppX Deployment operation failed for package Microsoft.ScreenSketch_2022.2303.17.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe with error 0x80073CF6. The specific error text for this failure is: An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
```

Attempting to uninstall the package via powershell results in the following message:

```
Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2209.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Remove-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF1, Package was not found.
```

Comment: Try using the power shell method to install the snipping app..   https://windowsreport.com/reinstall-snipping-tool-windows-11/   .   Look down the article for the command (power shell) method.

Comment: What command did you use exactly to uninstall it? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @John Added the results of the powershell command

Comment: You most likely need to repair Windows.  Do a Windows 11 Repair Install.

Comment: @RobWaterhouse95 [Troubleshooting packaging, deployment, and query of Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting) might help - read to the end.

Comment: @RobWaterhouse95 Also, search on the computer for "troubleshoot" and choose the "Other troubleshooters" link - there should be one for Windows Store apps.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this was one other troubleshoot step I tried but it did not help. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the reinstall command in the link provided by @John

Source: https://windowsreport.com/reinstall-snipping-tool-windows-11/

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register “$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode}
```

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the power shell method to install the snipping app..

[Manage Windows 11 Snipping Tool with Power Shell](https://windowsreport.com/reinstall-snipping-tool-windows-11/)

Look down the article for the command (power shell) method. –

Remove-AppxPackage Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2209.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2209.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode

One can also use:

Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register “$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode}

Answer (score 0):

FYI SnippingTool is a store app... so you can simply install it using the Microsoft Store in Windows 11. Direct link here: https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZ95KL8MR0L?ocid=pdpshare

When using the Get-AppxPackage method in this thread... please limit it to only the SnippingTool app by adding it to the call to Get-AppxPackage

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.ScreenSketch
```